# Unknown MySQL server host STARTING (0)

Tags: php, mysql

I am putting the csv file content into the database. My script will first check if the csv file is present in a particular location, if yes it will be executed and tables will be updated. For this,I have kept below query in a file (6sql.sql)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "($_GET["FileName"]) 
INTO TABLE test.LoadedEmployee 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," 
ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY `\` 
LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n" STARTING BY ''
```

(`$_GET["FileName"]`) will get the user input)

& from cmd prompt, I am trying to run cmd

```
mysql -u root -pdbase -hlocalhost -t -vvv -e "source C:\6sql.sql"
```

But I am getting below error

> Error: ERROR 2005 (HY000) at line 1: Unknown MySQL server host 'STARTING' (0)

Comment: I don't use MySQL but I think I always saw it like this: `mysql -u root -p root -h localhost < "C:\6sql.sql"`, i.e. there was a space between every option and its argument. But, like I said, I'm not actually a MySQL user, so can't be sure. Hopefully someone will correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I tried putting below querry, but it still trowing same error:
LOAD DATA INFILE "($_GET["FileName"]) INTO TABLE test.LoadedEmployee FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," ENCLOSED BY `` ESCAPED BY `\\` LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n" STARTING BY ``

Comment: I am putting the csv file content into the database. My script will first check if the csv file is present in a particular location, if yes it will be executed and tables will be updated.
For this,I have kept below querry in a file (6sql.sql)
LOAD DATA INFILE "($_GET["FileName"]) INTO TABLE test.LoadedEmployee FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," ENCLOSED BY `` ESCAPED BY `\\` LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n" STARTING BY ``

& 4m cmd prompt, I am trying 2 run cmd
mysql -u root -pdbase -hlocalhost -t -vvv -e "source C:\6sql.sql"

Error:
ERROR 2005 (HY000) at line 1: Unknown MySQL server host 'STARTING' (0)

Comment: Whem I am manually running the command LOAD... its running fine..so the permission is not an issue here...
I am not able to check the link " See here for reference" from my office as it is blocked :( so cant comment on it..

Comment: Should be the some security risks on scripting side  :( Not much aware about the php script :(

Comment: please  edit your question little clearer seems missing something  it would be better for all to understand  @user1777416

Comment: Is you host is localhost so other? Please confirm this or remove localhost if you are using ssh to upload sql on same server.

Comment: try by removing -h localhost...

Comment: maybe mysqlimport.exe works for you? `The mysqlimport client provides a command-line interface to the LOAD DATA INFILE SQL statement. Most options to mysqlimport correspond directly to clauses of LOAD DATA INFILE syntax.` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlimport.html

Comment: Thank a very lot...it workrd @NesimRazon
Below querry which worked :
mysqlimport -uroot -pdbase --local test "%UserInput%" --fields-terminated-by=","